# Insert into array based on items insert date

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, pdo

I am trying to make an array with posts in them, now, i need to insert the posts into the array based on their post date, eg if a post was posted on day 4 it will come after the post that was posted on day 5, so the newest posts gets added and displayed first, is there a good way to do this?

Comment: Would it be ok to insert them all as they come and then sort when you're done inserting, or they actually need to be inserted in correct order?

Comment: You should convert the post dates to unix timestamps with strtotime(), then order them in ascending order and after you could format them back to desired format.

Comment: Just make the date field first in SELECT clause and then use fetchAll() with [PDO::FETCH_GROUP](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#group)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest and not right method at all:

```
$sortedNews = []; //sorted news
foreach($newsArray as $news) {
  $sortedNews[strtotime($news['date'])] = $news; //take date and switch to unix timestamp as key of value
}
krsort($sortedNews); //sort by key (reverse) new to old
```

The right way it's let your database sort it itself `` ORDER BY `date` DESC ``

Comment: I am sorting it in the SQL statement but i need to run 2 different querys, one for the user and one for the friends posts, that's why i need to sort the array